# Copy table row and increment all name attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's have a table like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="FirstName1" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="LastName1" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="FirstName2" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="LastName2" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I want to have a button that will add new row at the end of the table with incremented name attributes so it will look like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="FirstName1" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="LastName1" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="FirstName2" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="LastName2" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="FirstName3" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="LastName3" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And so on.

So far I have this but it does not increment name attributes:

```
$("#newRowButton").click(function(){
  $("table tr:last").clone().appendTo("table");
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("#newRowButton").click(function() {
  $("table tr:last")
      .clone()
      .appendTo("table")
      .find(':input')
      .attr('name', function(index, name) {
          return name.replace(/(\d+)$/, function(fullMatch, n) {
              return Number(n) + 1;
          });
      })
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G5ZVr/1/).

Comment: Will that also increment a `name` that's an array, like `name="attendee[0]['firstname']"`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#newRowButton").click(function(){
   var trows = $("table tr:last").clone();
   trows.find('td input').attr("name",function(i,a){
   var p = new RegExp("((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(\\d+)",["i"]);
   var m = p.exec(a);
   var index = parseInt(m[1]);
   index++;
   return m[0]+index;
   });
   trows.appendTo("table");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var clonedRow = $("#EventType tr:last").clone();
$("input", clonedRow).attr('name', 'FirstName3'); // reset the name
```

you can get the name attribute and increment by 1

[Reference](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-cloning-a-table-row-and-changing-its-form-field-ids)