# Increment key within multidimensional array in a form's input field using jQuery clone

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to piece together info from these two answers, but neither seems to cover the issue in a way that I can extrapolate and get to work for my situation. So please don't punish me if this seems like a duplicate; I don't think it is.

[Increment multidimensional array when form fields are cloned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466324/increment-multidimensional-array-when-form-fields-are-cloned)

[Copy table row and increment all name attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674764/copy-table-row-and-increment-all-name-attributes)

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="pricing['prices'][0]['label']" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pricing['prices'][0]['price']" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pricing['prices'][0]['expires']" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pricing['prices'][0]['bulk-price']" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pricing['prices'][0]['bulk-qty']" value="" /></td>
</tr>
```

is what I'm trying to clone, using this button:

```
<input type="button" id="newRowButton" value="Add Another Price" />
```

Script (so far the cloning works, but it doesn't change the "0" to a "1". I'm clearly missing something that I couldn't figure out by piecing together the examples in the other two answers)

```
$("#newRowButton").live('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $("table.tablearray tr:last")
      .clone()
      .find(':input')
      .each(function(){
            this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]$/,
                                          function(str,p1){
                                              return '[' + (parseInt(p1,10)+1) + ']';
                                          });
        })
    .end()
    .appendTo("table")
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Ideally I'd also like to add a "delete row" button too.

Comment: can you modify the html (add and attribute)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take out the `$` sign from the regex so it's like this:

```
$("#newRowButton").live('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $("table.tablearray tr:last")
      .clone()
      .find(':input')
      .each(function(){
            this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function(str,p1){
                return '[' + (parseInt(p1,10)+1) + ']';
            });
        })
    .end()
    .appendTo("table")
});
```

The `$` was forcing it to look for `[0]` at the end of the name which is not what you have.

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/S9Q8W/

Comment: What a beautiful answer. Worked perfect for what I needed, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a slight error in your regex:

```
this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]$/,
```

This only matches `[0]` when that is the *end* of the element's name, because `$` means "the end of the string".  If you remove that, the transformation works fine:

```
this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/,
                                      function(str,p1){
                                          return '[' + (parseInt(p1,10)+1) + ']';
                                      });
```